# Why is WebLogic sometimes not respecting session timeout in web.xml?

Tags: session, weblogic

Weblogic 12.1.3.

I have session-timeout set to 120 minutes in web.xml.

I created 10 sessions, and then watched the WebLogic console. 9 out of 10 timed out at the time expected, but 1 of the 10 did not.

The WebLogic console currently shows the current time is 4:25, the last access time for that thread is 2:15, and the max inactive interval is 7200 seconds, so it should have timed out roughly 10 minutes ago.

This is also happening on a larger scale in our production environment, with unpleasant consequences. (These not-timing-out sessions stick around indefinitely, until the server is rebooted.)

Things I checked:

- weblogic.xml does not have a timeout set.
- I did a full text search in *.java for setMaxInactiveInterval and found no results.
- The timeout in the WebLogic console is shorter than the timeout in web.xml.
- There are no settings under Deployment Plan.